# Increment efficiently over a sequence of integers in byte representation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to concatenate a sequence of integers with a list of tokens in a single byte string, so that, for example, the following:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

would become (with 1 byte for the integer representation):

```
b'\x00foo'
b'\x01bar'
b'\x02baz'
```

The best I've come up with looks like this:

```
for i, token in zip(range(256), "foo bar baz".split()):
    print(i.to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder) + token.encode())
```

However the iteration itself involves conversion between Python's integer and bytes at each step in the loop, so that it is much slower (10 times for me) than to simply iterate over the integers.

The question is: is there a way to iterate directly over the *byte string representation* of the integers, and not the integer themselves?

Comment: How many times would you need to do the iteration per program run?

Comment: Well, something like 4 million times :)

Comment: Well, I was going to suggest pre-building all the bytes as a string, with something like `byte_chars = bytes(range(256))` and using that in the `zip` then concatenating, but it looks like iterating over a `bytes` object returns an integer in Python 3.x, so it's not really much help. It'd work in Python 2.x tho', and may out-perform `struct.pack()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think might be faster:

```
from struct import pack

for i, token in enumerate(b"foo bar bazq".split()):
    print(pack('@B%ds' % len(token), i, token))
```

Output:

```
b'\x00foo'
b'\x01bar'
b'\x02bazq'
```

If you only have or want 3 character strings you could use the simpler `print` function/statement:

```
    print(pack('@B3s', i, token))
```

Comment: This is actually faster, and works in Python3. I'll actually use it for the Python3 version of my program. Thanks!

Comment: This will work in both Python 2 or 3. Change it to `print(repr(pack('@B%ds' % len(token), i, token)))` to convince yourself.

Comment: If you have a fixed-width token you can also use numpy, vectorizing the operation to avoiding the loop. This may be faster for high number of elements. Probably not useful if you just need to print the data though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy and access directly the buffer interface to avoid conversions:

On python 2.7 (numpy 1.7.1), this code:

```
N = arange(256, dtype='uint8')
for i, token in enumerate("foo bar baz".split()):
    print repr(N.data[i] + token.encode())
```

gives:

```
'\x00foo'
'\x01bar'
'\x02baz'
```

Comment: What version of numpy are you using? For me `N.data` yields integers, not bytes.

Comment: Tried on 1.7.1 but I doubt that the data interface has changed recently. For me the above example works in python 2.7. I used print repr(N.data[i] + token.encode()) to "see" the binary data.

Comment: I've got 1.8.0 on my side. Perhaps it is a change in Python3. Anyway, your answer still solves the problem for python2, so +1 and accept.

Answer (score 1):

In case of a fixed-width token (let say 3 chars) a numpy record-array can be used.

This is handy if your purpose is not only printing the data but storing it in some convenient form, with a specific bit order. And of course the longer the number of elements/records the more efficient this approach is.

In the following example the string length is fixed to 3:

```
# Create a record array
x = np.zeros((3,),dtype=('u1,a3'))
# Fill the array
x[:] = [(n,s) for n, s in zip(arange(256, dtype='u1'), 'foo bar bax'.split())]
```

Output:

```
array([(0, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'), (2, 'bax')], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'u1'), ('f1', 'S3')])
```

Now you can use all the numpy functions to process the data. For example you can obtain an array of the numeric fields (field 0, named by default 'f0') with:

```
x['f0']
```

and of the string fields with:

```
x['f1']
```

These are "views" of the original array and will not use more memory. More info on numpy record arrays can be found on the [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).

**NB:** As far as I know, this approach should work on both python 2.x and 3.x.